# akka-sbt-plugin specifying outputDirectory in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have a build.sbt with the following settings

```
import akka.sbt.AkkaKernelPlugin                                                                                                 

import akka.sbt.AkkaKernelPlugin.{ Dist, outputDirectory, distJvmOptions} 

AkkaKernelPlugin.distSettings                                                                                                    

outputDirectory := file("dist1") .
```

But when I run dist . The output still goes to target/dist.

How can I fix this without using a build.scala file ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use: `(outputDirectory in Dist) := file("dist1")`